# How does one organize the coefficients of PolynomialFeatures in Lexicographical order so that they match sympy for a multivariate polynomial?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sympy, polynomials, lexicographic

I had a set of parameters that I manually (I want it manual) fitted with the pseudo-inverse using [PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.fit_transform):

```
poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=Degree_mdl)
Kern_train = poly_feat.fit_transform(X_train)
c_pinv = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv( Kern_train ),Y_train)
```

then I had some multivariate polynomial that I simplified with the help of sympy by using the [poly](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html) class and the `coeffs()` function. Though, the coeffs function says it returns the non-zero coeffs in **lex order**. Thus, I just wanted to know how I can get the order of PolynomialFeatures to match the above so that I can compare coefficients term by term if I needed.

Does someone know how to match the order of the two so that such comparison is possible?

---

I do know what lexicographical order means from looking a [mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html) which I think makes intuitive sense to me (basically the lexicographical order is done by the degree of the monomial so xy x^2 and y^2 all have same order and are "larger" than any degree one term like x or y). However, the detail I think it boils down is to find out how sympy vs PolynomialFeatures order things. Sympy says it orders lexicographically but when I inspect my polynomials it does not seem to obey the order I would have expected (while PolyFeatures does obey some order but then breaks dies in some unknown way to me when it has multiple terms of the same order like x^2y, xy^2, y^2). So this is what came out when I inspected sympy:

```
(Pdb) s_expr
Poly(-4.92243832500572e-13*x1**3 - 3.86418002630562e-13*x1**2*x2 - 284.848327636719*x1**2 - 1.97301728991142e-13*x1*x2**2 - 11.1939144134521*x1*x2 + 66.1333587984857*x1 - 1.35329085177577e-13*x2**3 - 108.171173095703*x2**2 + 28.227414137076*x2 - 11.0110442095318, x1, x2, domain='RR')
(Pdb) s_expr.coeffs()
[-4.92243832500572e-13, -3.86418002630562e-13, -284.848327636719, -1.97301728991142e-13, -11.1939144134521, 66.1333587984857, -1.35329085177577e-13, -108.171173095703, 28.2274141370760, -11.0110442095318]
(Pdb) s_expr.coeffs()[::-1]
[-11.0110442095318, 28.2274141370760, -108.171173095703, -1.35329085177577e-13, 66.1333587984857, -11.1939144134521, -1.97301728991142e-13, -284.848327636719, -3.86418002630562e-13, -4.92243832500572e-13]
```

and this is what came out when I inspected PolynomailFeatures:

```
>>> xx
array([[2, 3]])
>>> poly_feat.fit_transform(xx)
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   6.,   9.,   8.,  12.,  18.,  27.]])
# maps to the following ordering:
## [1,x1,x2,x1^2,x1x2,x2^2,x1^3,x1^2x2,x1x2^2,x2^3]
```

so right now I am looking and these and wondering how I can make them have **the exact same ordering** including when monomials have the same order. Any ideas would be really helpful.

I've taken a look at their source code but I have not been able to digest it fully to understand whats going on (specially on the sympy side). Any help is appreciated!

I only worked examples with degree 3 and 2 input dimensions but it would be nice for it to work for arbitrary inputs and degree.

---

Bounty section: making 3 dimension with degree 3 work (and above I hope)

I've tried to make the coefficients match for for dimension 3 and for degree 3 but they don't match for some reasons. It doesn't seem PolyFeatures is using either of `grevlex`,`grlex` if anyone has any idea how to make it would I'd love to hear it. I made the coefficients of the polinomial match what the value should be for that monomial if the inputs where `[x3,x2,x1] = [5,3,2]` so for example the coefficient for `x3**2` has a coefficient of `25` or if `x2*x3**2` has a coefficient of `75`. So the output I get is:

```
    x_poly_feat_list =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10, 9, 15, 25, 8, 12, 20, 18, 30, 50, 27, 45, 75, 125]
    poly =  Poly(125*x3**3 + 75*x3**2*x2 + 50*x3**2*x1 + 25*x3**2 + 45*x3*x2**2 + 30*x3*x2*x1 + 15*x3*x2 + 20*x3*x1**2 + 10*x3*x1 + 5*x3 + 27*x2**3 + 18*x2**2*x1 + 9*x2**2 + 12*x2*x1**2 + 6*x2*x1 + 3*x2 + 8*x1**3 + 4*x1**2 + 2*x1 + 1, x3, x2, x1, domain='ZZ')
    c_grevlex =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10, 9, 15, 25, 8, 12, 20, 18, 30, 50, 27, 45, 75, 125]
    c_grlex =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15, 25, 8, 12, 18, 27, 20, 30, 45, 50, 75, 125]
    len(c_grlex) 20
    len(c_grevlex) 20
    len(x_poly_feat_list) 20
    all_match_grlex =  False
    all_match_grevlex =  False
```

which means that it doesn't match.

full code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

# nb monomials (n+d,d), d=degree, n=# of inputs

def check(n,d,user_array=None):
    if user_array is None:
        x = np.arange(2,2+n).reshape(1,n) # e.g. array([[2, 3]])
    else:
        x = user_array.reshape(1,n)
    #x = np.arange(2,2+n).reshape(1,n) # e.g. array([[2, 3]])
    print('x = ', x)
    ##
    poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(d)
    x_poly_feat = poly_feat.fit_transform(x)
    ##
    x_poly_feat_list = [ int(i) for i in x_poly_feat[0]]
    #print('x_poly_feat = ', x_poly_feat)
    #print('x_poly_feat = ', list(x_poly_feat[0]))
    print('x_poly_feat_list = ', x_poly_feat_list)
    return x_poly_feat_list

def check_sympy_degree():
    x3,x2,x1 = symbols('x3 x2 x1')
    poly = Poly( 125*x3**3 + 75*x2*x3**2 + 45*x2**2*x3 + 27*x2**3 + 50*x1*x3**2 + 30*x1*x2*x3 + 18*x1*x2**2 + 20*x1**2*x3 + 12*x1**2*x2
        + 8*x1**3 + 25*x3**2 + 15*x2*x3 + 9*x2**2 + 10*x1*x3 + 6*x1*x2 + 4*x1**2 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 5*x3 + 1,(x3,x2,x1) )
    c_grevlex = poly.coeffs(order='grevlex')
    c_grlex = poly.coeffs(order='grlex')
    print('poly = ',poly)
    print('c_grevlex = ', c_grevlex[::-1])
    print('c_grlex = ', c_grlex[::-1])
    return c_grlex, c_grevlex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #check(n=2,d=3)
    ##
    x_poly_feat_list = check(n=3,d=3,user_array=np.array([2,3,5]))
    ##
    c_grlex, c_grevlex = check_sympy_degree()
    print('len(c_grlex)',len(c_grlex))
    print('len(c_grevlex)',len(c_grevlex))
    print('len(x_poly_feat_list)',len(x_poly_feat_list))
    all_match_grlex = all( c_grlex[i] == x_poly_feat_list for i in range(len(x_poly_feat_list)) )
    all_match_grevlex = all( c_grevlex[i] == x_poly_feat_list for i in range(len(x_poly_feat_list)) )
    print('all_match_grlex = ',all_match_grlex)
    print('all_match_grevlex = ',all_match_grevlex)
```

Answer (score 4):

So, the PolynomialFeatures order of monomials is as follows:

```
1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 4*x1**2 + 5*x1*x2 + 6*x2**2 + 7*x1**3 + 8*x1**2*x2 + 9*x1*x2**2 + 10*x2**3
```

and we want SymPy to return the coefficients in the order shown: 1..10.

First thing to realize is that this is not a lexicographic order but *graded* (possibly reverse?) lexicographic order (see [Monomial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) on Wikipedia). Namely, the monomials are first separated (i.e., graded) by their total degree, and then lexicographic order is applied in each group.

SymPy's method `coeffs` supports the orders 'lex' (lexicographic, default), 'grlex' (graded lexicographic), and grevlex (reverse graded lexicographic). However, in order to produce the result we want it's necessary to make two adjustments:

- when constructing the polynomial, declare the order of variables as `(x2, x1)` using the second argument of Poly constructor.
- reverse the list of coefficients from `coeffs`.

The combined effect of these two adjustments is to put the smaller total degrees first, while maintaining the order between the monomials of the same total degree.

Example:

```
q = Poly(1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 4*x1**2 + 5*x1*x2 + 6*x2**2 + 7*x1**3 + 8*x1**2*x2 + 9*x1*x2**2 + 10*x2**3, (x2, x1))
c = q.coeffs(order='grevlex')[::-1]
print(c)
```

This prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Important: grlex and grevlex coincide for 1 and 2 variables. Since your example is in 2 variables, I don't know whether 'grevlex' or 'grlex' is correct in general; I used 'grevlex' on a hunch, but you should test this with a polynomial of more than 2 variables.

Comment: why does `(x2,x1)` vs `(x1,x2)` matter?

Comment: Because to apply any of the aforementioned orders of monomials, one has to order the _variables_ first. Lexicographic order in a dictionary relies on the letters being ordered: A is before B, and B is before C. This is what (x2, x1) says: x2 is before x1.

Comment: just out of curiosity why can't we tell what the right input just by looking at 1D and 2D inputs?

Comment: Because, as I said in the last paragraph, grlex and grevlex are the same thing for 1 or 2 variables; they are different for 3 or more.

Comment: seems your right `grevlex ` is the right order to use.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the right answer is `grevlex` according to the code I produced. Hope it helps people.

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

import pdb

# nb monomials (n+d,d), d=degree, n=# of inputs

def check(n,d,user_array=None):
    if user_array is None:
        x = np.arange(2,2+n).reshape(1,n) # e.g. array([[2, 3]])
    else:
        x = user_array.reshape(1,n)
    #x = np.arange(2,2+n).reshape(1,n) # e.g. array([[2, 3]])
    print('x = ', x)
    ##
    poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(d)
    x_poly_feat = poly_feat.fit_transform(x)
    ##
    x_poly_feat_list = [ int(i) for i in x_poly_feat[0]]
    #print('x_poly_feat = ', x_poly_feat)
    #print('x_poly_feat = ', list(x_poly_feat[0]))
    print('x_poly_feat_list = ', x_poly_feat_list)
    return x_poly_feat_list

def check_sympy_degree():
    x3,x2,x1 = symbols('x3 x2 x1')
    poly = Poly( 125*x3**3 + 75*x2*x3**2 + 45*x2**2*x3 + 27*x2**3 + 50*x1*x3**2 + 30*x1*x2*x3 + 18*x1*x2**2 + 20*x1**2*x3 + 12*x1**2*x2
        + 8*x1**3 + 25*x3**2 + 15*x2*x3 + 9*x2**2 + 10*x1*x3 + 6*x1*x2 + 4*x1**2 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 5*x3 + 1,(x3,x2,x1) )
    c_grevlex = poly.coeffs(order='grevlex')[::-1]
    c_grlex = poly.coeffs(order='grlex')[::-1]
    print('poly = ',poly)
    return c_grevlex, c_grlex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #check(n=2,d=3)
    ##
    x_poly_feat_list = check(n=3,d=3,user_array=np.array([2,3,5]))
    ##
    c_grevlex, c_grlex = check_sympy_degree()
    #c_grevlex = len(c_grevlex)*[-1]

    print('c_grevlex = ', c_grevlex)
    print('c_grlex = ', c_grlex)

    print('len(c_grevlex)',len(c_grevlex))
    print('len(c_grlex)',len(c_grlex))
    print('len(x_poly_feat_list)',len(x_poly_feat_list))

    match_grevlex_list = [ c_grevlex[i] == x_poly_feat_list[i] for i in range(len(x_poly_feat_list)) ]
    match_grlex_list = [ c_grlex[i] == x_poly_feat_list[i] for i in range(len(x_poly_feat_list)) ]

    all_match_grevlex = all( match_grevlex_list )
    all_match_grlex = all( match_grlex_list )

    print('match_grevlex_list = ',match_grevlex_list)
    print('match_grlex_list =',match_grlex_list)

    print('all_match_grevlex = ',all_match_grevlex)
    print('all_match_grlex = ',all_match_grlex)
```